# how to get values for same column name from two different tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How to get values for same column name from two different tables in SQL?

column name is `emp_id` loacated in these two tables: `company,employee`.

Comment: For retrieving data from database, you need to write a query. Have you ever tried one? If yes, plese put in what you have written for this.

Comment: you want to get merged data from those 2 columns ? if yes then try union

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to diffrentiate between same field names of two tables in a select query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800866/how-to-diffrentiate-between-same-field-names-of-two-tables-in-a-select-query)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want data in seperate columns from two tables then try :

```
SELECT c.emp_id, emp.emp_id 
FROM company c
INNER JOIN employee emp on c.company_id = emp.company_id
```

If you want to merge both columns data then use this :

```
SELECT emp_id FROM company
UNION
SELECT emp_id FROM employee
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get the results:

```
company.emp_id, employee.emp_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the name of the table before the name of the colomn with a "." between, like:

```
SELECT company.emp_id, employe.emp_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you are asking, something like the example below, but if you provide a sample query, it would help...

```
select emp.emp_id,company.emp_id
from company
join employee emp on emp.company_id=company_company_id
```