# SQL With clause, same column name in different tables

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I have two different tables. mode_table and station_table. They both have a column called day_column. I want to have the records from each table which day_column is greater than 20.
I am not sure if I am allowed to use the same alias (day_Val) in both tables. Is this correct?

```
WITH
active_mode AS (
  SELECT (IF(day_column > '20', 0, 1)) AS day_Val
  FROM mode_table
),
active_station AS (
  SELECT (IF(day_column > '20', 0, 1)) AS day_Val
  FROM station_table
)
SELECT day_column, day_val
FROM active_mode, active_station
WHERE day_Val != 1
```

The reason for this question is I have around 14 tables and I do not want to create 14 alias and use just one.
The goal is to report any row in all those 14 tables that has day_column > 20. All the tables have a column named day_column.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get values for same column name from two different tables in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513669/how-to-get-values-for-same-column-name-from-two-different-tables-in-sql)

Comment: Of course you can. You can have 20000000 repeated names if you want, as long as they're not repeated with the same table. To access them you simply prefix them with the table name/alias followed by a do, so `TableName.Col, AnotherTable.Col1`

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want `union all`:

```
select . . .   -- whatever columns you want
from mode_table m
where day_column > 20
union all
select . . . 
from station_table s
where day_column > 20
```

Comment: Why are you assuming that both tables have the same structure?

Comment: @PM77-1 . . . Because the columns being chosen are a bit non-sensical.  I adjusted the answer.

Comment: @PM77-1 probably because the guy posted the structure...I'd say Gordon's answer adjusts appropriately to the question.

Comment: @TheRedMetalRooster  Are you sure? Where exactly?

Comment: He's posting his CTEs. If OP has more columns, it would be on him for not mentioning it, but Gordon's answer is in line with the code shown. He's saying he has 2 CTE with only 1 column: day_val, which is formed from the results of an IF statement operating on another column called day_column, both with the same logic. I would say it's fair to assume the columns in questions are identical.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem I can find from your script is there is no column called “day_column” from both “active_mode” and active_station.

Regarding to your question, the answer is yes, but not the way you are doing, you may consider to use a union all statement

For example

Select
Date_val
From active_mode
Union all
Select
Date_val
From active_station

Otherwise, it will cause ambiguity to the server as it don’t know which table expression are you referring to.